# Using Inline Entity Form in Drupal how to calculate and display in the parent form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I have trouble calculating values from the inline entity form fields and showing them on the parent form.

Using the Tamper:Math, I was able to calculate sub-totals within the inline forms using ECA as described by in [this video](https://tube.tchncs.de/w/3gDpeV9TynLeoxk4XQfZ7c).

I wonder how to sum up the sub-total values from the IEFs and set it to the grand total field of the parent form, ideally using ECA.
I tried asking the same in the [Drupal website ECA issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/eca/issues/3363022#comment-15219404) but have not yet received an answer.

Thank you in advance for the support.